Athrava-veda hairfall treatment
In the vol 6.21, 6.136, 6.137 of Athavaveda. Two herbs are mentioned to promote hairgrowth namely (revatis, nitatni).
Can some please provide the scientific name or any english name of these two plants?

This question isn't within the scope of Hinduism and cannot be answered as such, please do your own research on this matter or bring it up tangentially in a discussion on some other subject regarding Ayurveda.

Then where should I ask this question, in cristian community? If you know please answer it or else leave..
